# Java this and generics?

Tags: java, generics, this

I would like to implement a callback functionality as you see below. My problem is how I can pass the current object to the `Bar.start(Foo<T> foo)` method.
    public interface IBar {
      public void start(Foo foo);
    }

```
public class Bar<T> implements IBar<T> {

  public void start(Foo<T> foo) {
    new Thread() {
      while (true) {
        T baz = foo.getT();
        //do something with the T baz object
        foo.callback();
      }
    }.start();
  }

}

public Class Foo<T> {
  private T baz;
  private Bar<T> bar;

  public Foo(T baz, Bar<T> bar) {
    this.baz = baz;
    this.bar = bar;
  }

  public void startBar() {
    bar.start(this); //---- Here I got this is not possible. 
  }

  public T getT() {
    return baz;
  }

  public void callBack() {
    system.out.println("called back");
  }
}
```

I would like to take the advantage of type T, so I would like to use generics. I extended the code to make it clear, here is my main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String s = new String("one");
  Integer i = new Integer(1);
  Bar<String> bar1 = new Bar<String>();
  Bar<Integer> bar2 = new Bar<Integer>();
  Foo<String> foo1 = new Foo<String>(s, bar1);
  Foo<Integer> foo2 = new Foo<Integer>(i, bar2);
  foo1.startBar();
  foo2.startBar();
}
```

Comment: Does it even compile? Your `Bar` doesn't implement `start` from `IBar`. If you fil that, i suspect it would work. Edit: seems like you fixed it, and it was a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After fixing numerous typos in your code, it [compiled fine](http://ideone.com/4ylIKt):

```
public interface IBar<T> {
  public void start(Foo<T> foo);
}

public class Bar<T> implements IBar<T> {

  public void start(final Foo<T> foo) {
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          while (true) {
            T baz = foo.getT();
            //do something with the T baz object
            foo.callBack();
          }
        }
    }.start();
  }

}

public class Foo<T> {
  private T baz;
  private Bar<T> bar;

  public Foo(T baz, Bar<T> bar) {
    this.baz = baz;
    this.bar = bar;
  }

  public void startBar() {
    bar.start(this); // totally possible
  }

  public T getT() {
    return baz;
  }

  public void callBack() {
    System.out.println("called back");
  }
}
```

Comment: You have right, thanks. I found the mistake in my code as well.

Answer (score 2):

Make an interface with method `callBack`.

```
public interface ICallBack{
    void callBack();
}
```

Make class `Foo` implement this interface. Make method `startBar` accept a parameter of `ICallBack` type

```
 publis void startBar(ICallBack callBack) {
        new Thread() {
          while (true) {
            //do something
            callBack.callback();
          }
        }.start();
      }
```

Comment: `interface` is better suited for your requirement

Answer (score 0):

Create an association of Foo inside bar. At the time of initializing Bar inside foo, pass this object and use it bar.start()

```
public class Bar implements IBar {

Foo foo;

//setters and getters

      publis void startBar(Foo foo) {
       // use foo here
        new Thread() {
          while (true) {
            //do something
            foo.callback();
          }
        }.start();
      }

    }
```

Now inside foo set foo like

```
bar.setFoo(this);// or u can use constructor instead of getter & setter
```